# useEffect infinite loop even with empty array as dependency

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

i'm runnig the code below but it couses an infinite rerender in component. super weirred

```
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const token = useSelector(state => state.token)
    
    const getUser = async () => {
            try {
              const response = await baseUrl.get('/users/getUser', {
                headers: {
                  authorization: token
                }
              })
              dispatch(SET_USER(response.data.user))
            } catch (error) {
              Alert.alert(error.response.data.message)
            }
          }
          
    useEffect(()=>{
       getUser()
    },[])
```

Comment: Are you sure there is noting more, which force re-render ?

Comment: yes. if i comment out above code , it works fine

Comment: put all the code, by the moment all is ok

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing some dependencies, try to add dependency for useEffect, in turn wrap getuser with useCallback, and also add dependencies for useCallback hook.

```
const getUser = useCallback(async () => {
      try {
              const response = await baseUrl.get('/users/getUser', {
                headers: {
                  authorization: token
                }
              })
              dispatch(SET_USER(response.data.user))
            } catch (error) {
              Alert.alert(error.response.data.message)
            }
  },[dispatch, SET_USER]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, [getUser]);
```